# Magento - Apply discount on Shipping Amount

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I cannot figure it out. How to apply discount to the basket amount before shipping. I see an option in Shopping Cart Price Rule "Apply to Shipping Amount" but what every amount or the way i enter it apply to the total amount not to the shipping amount.

The offer is for one product. Customer buy product A for 30 euro plus shipping but if the customer buy one more of product A he will get the second one for 20 euro + no shipping. i have solved the price but cant solve the shipping price issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually the way it is suppose to work. I think the wording is confusing, it should be something like : "Apply Discount After Shipping Costs is added", or something like that.

Basically, setting Apply to Shipping amount to ON will make the discount work like this:

> Total = (Subtotal + Shipping) - Discount Amount

While leaving the setting off will do this:

> Total = (Subtotal - Discount Amount) + Shipping

In this case, if your Subtotal is lower than you discount, your Subtotal will be adjusted to 0 but the customer will still have to pay for shipping.